# How to persist data on a volume when using docker swarm mode?

Tags: postgresql, docker, yaml, docker-swarm

New to Docker and I'm trying to set Postgres and pgadmin4 to run as a single service on docker for Mac inside a virtual machine. Everything works but as soon as I stop the service my data is gone. I'm using a named volume to persist data but probably doing something wrong. What is it?

Here's my setup:

```
# create my VM
docker-machine create dbvm
# set the right environment
eval $(docker-machine env dbvm)
```

Here's my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_db
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/pgdata
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  pgadmin:
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    volumes:
      - pgadmindata:/pgadmindata
volumes:
  pgdata:
  pgadmindata:
```

With `docker-compose.yaml`, I run:

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml dbstack`

I can do everything on this setup, but if I run `docker stack rm dbstack` the data is gone after this, but the volumes still exist.

```
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               0c15b0b22c6b850e8768c14045da166253424dda4df8d2e13df75fd54d833412
local               22bab81d9d1de0e07de97363596b096f944752eba617ff574a0ab525239227f5
local               6da6e29fb98ad0f66d7da6a75dc76066ce014b26ea43567c55ed318fda707105
local               dbstack_pgadmindata
local               dbstack_pgdata
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have it in some config not shown, I believe you need to map to the default data location inside the container e.g., `pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: Guess my misunderstanding was that I could set a custom folder for data to be stored in my docker-compose file. This worked for postgres. pgadmin still doesn't work, so that's the next thing I'll try to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Idg is partially correct. postgres data lives at `/var/lib/postgresql/data` per the [Docker Hub readme](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

But for it to work in your named volume, you can't use a path on the left side, so correct value would be:

```
volumes:
  - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Then the postgres data will stay in that named volume, on the node it was created on.

Comment: Yeah, using the command as you typed worked, but not sure if I understand the "you can't use a path on the right side". How come `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is not conidered a path?

Comment: Hah, I mean *left* side, oops. will fix.